# JS: Confused on how to make a function return it's parameters concatenated

Tags: javascript, function, var

The issue I'm having is due to this question:

> Create a function named fullName that accepts 2 input parameters
>   called firstName and lastName. Within the function, concatenate both
>   of those variables together with a space in between. (e.g
>   fullName(“Brad”, “Pitt”) would return “Brad Pitt”

At the bottom of the lesson it should return fullName (Clark, Kent)
 and fullName (Jonah, Hex). and fullName should be a function.

I have tried:

```
function fullName ( firstName, lastName) { 
   return firstName + '' + lastName;   
}
```

and

```
 function fullName ( firstName, lastName) {   
       var firstName= " ";
       var LastName= " ";
       return firstName + '' + lastName; 
 }
```

I'm getting:

> firstName/ lastName is already defined

and on and on. I have tried so many different ways to attempt to answer this but nothing works.

Comment: Just call the function like this: fullname(firstName, LastName); and the function will it self return the combined values.

Comment: The first one would be fine if you replace the empty string `''` with a string containing a space (`' '`).

Answer (score 1):

Look, you need to know the difference of the parameter and a defined `var`

When you write: `function fullName(firstName, lastName){...}` you created a function that expects two parameters called `firstName` and `lastName`.
Now if inside the function you write: `var firstName = ...` you are trying to override the parameter name and it's not going to work (note that you can change the parameter value, but you can't create a new `var` with the same name), you need to create a variable with another name, such as `var fName = firstName` for example...

Be aware that javascript is case-sensitive, so `LastName` is different than `lastName`.

But to output what you want, there's no need to create additional variables inside the function. You need just the first example you have (but with a white space inside the quotes `" "`), that is this one:

```js
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

//calling the function and assigning the return to a variable
var fullname = fullName("Brad", "Pitt");

console.log(fullname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your first approach a little bit,

```
function fullName (firstName, lastName) { 
   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;   
}

console.log(fullName("Clark", "Kent")); //it will return "Clark Kent"
```

Comment: You may have forgotten the quotes `''` used to denominate strings in your example—right now it points to two variables named `Clark` and `Kent`, neither of which are defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: In JS , arguments passed in the function can be accessed directly, no need to declare them explicitly.

Comment: That's not the problem I'm trying to point out. What I'm trying to point out is that you're passing "Clark" and "Kent" in as variables, and I see no reason for them to have been defined previously by him in the question, nor are you defining them in your answer. The moment you try to run that code, it'll ReferenceError with the explanation that "Clark" has not been declared in any way

Comment: Ohh I got you , firstName and lastName should be passed as string while calling the function , Updating Answer

Comment: (I'm not the person who asked the question; I was just pointing out that your answer was incomplete because of the error you made)

Comment: Ooops.. Anyways Thanks

Comment: Hello Everyone, Thank you for all your answers, Wish I could have walked through it with you all. I am going to try out these new approaches now

Comment: You guys/ladies are awesome! Thank you, I have been stuck on this for two days racking my brain. Such a simple fix with spacing the  ' ' ( even tells me to do so in the assignment lol)  and creating a new var outside the function block. you are the best of people.